# How to escape a comma in a json string

Tags: json, string, escaping

Say i want to have the number 1,000,000 in a string like so:  "million": "1,000,000".  So it displays a million instead of 1000000.  How do I escape the commas in the string  I tried using \, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: put quotes around it, so that it's a string, in which case the commas do not need to be escaped. See http://json.org/ for which characters require escape.  In JSON string, should be: "million" : "1,000,000"

Comment: Uh? Commas don't have to be (and cannot be) escaped in JSON. I think it's not clear to me what your issue really is.

Comment: It's weird but when I put "1,000,000" or even "1,000" for some reason my application sees them as "1" and "000" and "000" or "1" and "000".  I'm saving the data as a CSV using jsreports.

Comment: I just tried the same scenario using the phantom pdf in jsreports and it rendered out the comma correctly as a comma and didn't separate the data so I'm guessing it's some to do with either jsreports or csv's (since they are COMMA separated values and that's what that comma is doing in the 1,000.